Backtracking not working on a Hitori matrix
It seems the code I wrote doesn't backtrack properly and i have no idea where the backtracking goes wrong.
Hitori is an "reverse" Sudoku. You are given a matrix filled with numbers and have to eliminate certain ones with these rules:

the number in a cell cannot be found anywhere else on its respective row and column (no duplicates)
final matrix has to be whole (no "islands" - isolated cells) - this part i'm checking with a DFS
i can't eliminate a cell which is adjacent to an eliminated cell.

BTW, I am not looking for efficiency for this hitori solver using backtracking. I just want to get a general grip of this.
For some cases this works, but for the example given i still have duplicate numbers left.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define DIM 5

int nr=0, marcaj[DIM][DIM] = {0}, matrice[DIM][DIM] = {
    {5, 1, 2, 3, 2},
    {5, 3, 2, 2, 4},
    {5, 2, 4, 5, 4},
    {3, 4, 5, 1, 2},
    {3, 5, 5, 4, 2},
    };

bool solutionFound = false;

void printMatrice() {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            printf("%d ", marcaj[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void dfs(bool visited[DIM][DIM], int row, int col) {
    int rowOffset[] = {-1, 0, 1, 0};
    int colOffset[] = {0, 1, 0, -1};

    visited[row][col] = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int newRow = row + rowOffset[i];
        int newCol = col + colOffset[i];

        if (newRow >= 0 && newRow < DIM && newCol >= 0 && newCol < DIM &&
            !visited[newRow][newCol] && marcaj[newRow][newCol] == 0) {
            dfs(visited, newRow, newCol);
        }
    }
}

bool areAllzerosConnected() {
    bool visited[DIM][DIM] = {false};
    bool startFound = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < DIM && !startFound; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            if (marcaj[i][j] == 0) {
                dfs(visited, i, j);
                startFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!startFound) return true;

    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            if (marcaj[i][j] == 0 && !visited[i][j]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool duplicat(int lin, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        if (marcaj[lin][i] == 0 && i != col && matrice[lin][i] == matrice[lin][col]) {
            return true;
        }
        if (marcaj[i][col] == 0 && i != lin && matrice[i][col] == matrice[lin][col]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool areAdjacentMarkedCells() {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            if (marcaj[i][j] == 1) {
                if ((i > 0 && marcaj[i - 1][j] == 1) ||
                    (i < DIM - 1 && marcaj[i + 1][j] == 1) ||
                    (j > 0 && marcaj[i][j - 1] == 1) ||
                    (j < DIM - 1 && marcaj[i][j + 1] == 1)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void bkt(int lin, int col) {
    if (solutionFound) return;

    if (lin == DIM) {
            printMatrice();
            printf("Numar mutari:%d\n",nr);
            solutionFound = true;
            return;
    }

    if (col == DIM) {
        bkt(lin + 1, 0);
        return;
    }

    if (duplicat(lin, col)) {
        nr++;
        marcaj[lin][col] = 1;
        if (areAllzerosConnected() && !areAdjacentMarkedCells()) {
            bkt(lin, col + 1);
        }

    }
    marcaj[lin][col] = 0;
    bkt(lin, col + 1);
}

int main() {
    bkt(0, 0);
    return 0;
}



When you exit the dfs function, shouldn't you be unflagging the cell as "visited"?

the issue isn't in the dfs function, i've checked it separately and it should work just fine. somehow the algorithm doesn't backtrack correctly
